# How can i detect numbers of color's available for a product

Tags: magento2

I have an issue in my project where color swatches are comming in proper way for desktop. But while in mobile I have added an icon where more color options are available. But it showing each product in mobile.

I need to add an icon by availability of color swatch. I don't know how to detect color options available for the product.

If any other way to solve this problem please help.